# SQL - Return UserIds that only reviewed an item as "poor"

Tags: sql, group-by, count, having-clause

What is the best way to query the below problem in SQL?

I want to return the UserID that *only reviewed items* as **"Poor"**.
In the table below, only `UserID 1` should be returned.

```
UserID   ItemID    Rank
-------|---------|----------
1      | 1       | Poor
2      | 1       | Fair
1      | 2       | Poor
2      | 2       | Excellent
2      | 3       | Poor
```

The query (based off of the table above) should return only the ID 1, as that ID never reviewed any other items as anything other than "Poor"

```
UserID
-------
1
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having min(rank) = max(rank) and
       min(rank) = 'Poor';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could aggregate and filter with a conditional `sum` in the `having` clause:

```
select userid
from mytable
group by userid
having sum(case when rank != 'Poor' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you are running MySQL, this gets even shorter:

```
select userid
from mytable
group by userid
having sum(rank != 'Poor') = 0
```